# Enviar dados pelo formulário sem refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

Boa noite, tenho um script de comentários, e queria que quando o usuário enviasse o comentário, ele permanecesse na mesma página que está, sem atualizar para a página do php. No momento quando ele envia a pergunta ele é redirecionado para o php que processa os dados. Tentei via ajax, mas ainda sim está redirecionando para a página php.

```html
<form method="post" action="insertcomment.php" id="form_comment">
        <h2 class="text-center text-muted" style="font-size: 18px;">Deixe um comentário:</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="name" name="nome" value="<?= $_SESSION['nome'] ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" type="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="Digite aqui seu comentário"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?= $_SESSION['id_usuario'] ?>" name="id_usuario">
      <input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="<?= $row['product_id'] ?>" name="product_id">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info mx-0 mx-auto text-center" value="Comentar">
      </div>
      <div id="resp"></div>
  </form>

<!---- SCRIPT DO FORMULARIO AJAX --->
<script> 
      $('#form_comment').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const nome = $('input[name="nome"]').val();
const comentario = $('input[name="comentario"]').val();
const id_usuario = $('input[name="id_usuario"]').val();
const product_id = $('textarea[name="product_id"]').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'insertcomment.php
', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
    type: 'POST',
    data: {nome: nome, comentario: comentario, id_usuario: id_usuario, product_id: product_id},
    success: function(response) {
        $('#resp').html(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
return false;
});
  </script>
```

página php que insere os dados no MYSQL

```html
<?php
require 'conexao_comment.php';

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['nome']));;
$comentario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['comentario']));;
$id_usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['id_usuario']));;
$product_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['product_id']));;

$sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios (id_usuario, product_id, nome, comentario) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$product_id', '$nome', '$comentario')";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

fiz algumas alterações no script do formulário uma delas foi adicionar um Event Listener. Fiz testes e funcionou perfeitamente ao clicar no botão "comentar" a requisição é feita, e o navegador não dá mais  refresh ao submeter o formulário.

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('#form_comment').addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    // Cancela o evento ao submeter o formulário
    e.preventDefault();
    // Com o objeto FormData conseguimos pegar os valores do formulário
    const data = new FormData(e.target);

    // Enviado o formulário
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        document.querySelector('#resp').innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/insertcomment.php");

    xhr.send(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Os dados não são inseridos no banco de dados.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode enviar enviar os dados do form mudando o botão de enviar e usando Jquery da seguinte maneira.

```
<input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar">

$('input#enviar').click(function () {
    $.post( 'url', $('form#form_comment').serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#resultadorelatorio').html(data.result);
        },'json'
    );
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou :(